# Destroy(free) every thing in a linklist-style stack?

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-management, data-structures

//it is not a very mature LINK-Stack currently ,I WILL UPDATE IT LATER.
I am trying to free every node in a `linklist-style` stack when I encountered this error:

according to solution 1, which is a compilable but un-executable script. Maybe my problem occured when I want to assign a address to (*S), BUT (*S) is freed ALREADY?

About the destroy function, I want to free every node in the RAM I allocated to (S) before ,making the RAM reusable.

So why the first function is unavailable????

PS:I have no idea about delete a variable in C,what I mean about delete is remove its address .Maybe the usual variable can not be freed by FREE()??

PPS: When I use the free(),I think it is just release of RAM ,but keep the name or identifier of the variable which may point to NULL or somwhere, it is dangerous ,but in Solution1,it seems I have to do so.

```
//IDE:Dev C++ 5.11 
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef int ElemType;

typedef struct Stack
{
    struct Stack *next;
    ElemType data;
} Stack,*LinkStack;

int InitStack(LinkStack *S) {
    *S = (LinkStack)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    if(!*S) return -1;
    (*S)->next=NULL;
    (*S)->data =0;
    printf("Maybe successfully initialized.\n");
    return 0;
}

int Push(LinkStack *S, ElemType e)
{
    LinkStack pt = (LinkStack)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    LinkStack newpt = (LinkStack)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    newpt->data = e;
    pt = (*S)->next;
    int number = 0;

    if (!pt)
    {
        printf("#a one time \n");
        (*S)->next = newpt;
        (*S)->data++;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (number < (*S)->data)
        {
            pt = pt->next;
            number++;
        }
        pt->next = newpt;
        newpt->next = NULL;
        (*S)->data++;
        return 0;
    }
}

int StackTraverse(LinkStack S)
{
    LinkStack pt = (LinkStack)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    pt = (S)->next;
    while (pt)
    {
        printf("%d__", pt->data);
        pt = pt->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

Solution1:  //unavailable
void DestroyStack(LinkStack *S)
{
    while (*S)
    {
        LinkList pt = (*S)->next;
        free(*S);
        (*S) = pt;
    }
    printf("Node destroyed!\n");
}

int main()
{
    LinkStack Sb;
    InitStack(&Sb);
    ElemType *e = (ElemType *)malloc(sizeof(ElemType));
    while (scanf("%d", e))
    {
        Push(&Sb, *e);
        printf("you have entered : %d.\n", *e);
    }
    free(e);
    printf("%d\n", Sb->next->next->data);
    StackTraverse(Sb);
    DestroyStack(&Sb);
    if (!Sb)
    {
        printf("succeed\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So I come up with another function !Using the Recursion，but when I insert 3 nodes to the `linklist-style` stack, it seems that the "**LinkStack destroyed**" is printed 6 times. When I insert 4 nodes, it prints 7 times.

```
solution2:  //available ,but not work well
void DestroyStack(LinkStack *S) {
    while(*S){
        LinkStack pt=(*S);
        (*S)=(*S)->next;
        printf("#a\n");
        DestroyStack(S);
    }
    printf("LinkStack Destroyed!");
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: OOPS!!!!I put up solution1 and solution2 at a wrong place ,the recrusion one is  avaliable ,but the other one is unavailable .

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @TobySpeight,So sorry for my fault in casually upload a question. I will follow your advise and making the question better....0.0Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole code is problematic, perhaps because you don't understand what `malloc` and `free` really do.

- `malloc` allocates a chunk of a certain size and gives you a handle to that memory. That handle is a pointer. That means that you only call `malloc` when you create an object. In your code, the only place where you should call it is `Push`, because you create a new node.
- You do not need to allocate memory for pointers that just traverse the stack. In particular,something like this:

  ```
  LinkStack pt = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
  pt = (S)->next;
  ```

  is wrong: You allocate memory and immediately lose the handle to it by assigning to `pt`. Throw out the `malloc` and keep only the second line.
- `free` gives the memory that was previousply allocated back to the system. Every `malloc` needs its corresponding `free`. Failing to do so is called a memory leak.
- Once you have called `free` on a pointer, you may no longer access the data behind it. The system function `free` doesnot set the pointer to `NULL`,so this is something you must be aware of.
- An empty stack is a stack that has no nodes. It is therefore pointless to allocate a dummy node. Your stack is defined by a pointer to its head node. You can just initialise this node to`NULL`:

  ```
  Stack *Sb = NULL;
  ```

  Likewise, you can check whether there are still items on the stack with:

  ```
  if (Sb) ...
  ```
- This is more a stylistic issue: It is considered bad practice to `typedef` away the pointer nature. You can `typedef` the struct, but instead `LinkStack`,just use `Stack *`, so that it is obvious at first sight that you are dealing with a pointer here.
- In `main`, you do the following:

  ```
  printf("%d\n", Sb->next->next->data);
  ```

  This is dangerous,because you don't know whether the user has entered at least three items. You must check pointers for `NULL` before dereferencing.

Let's put this into practice: Pushing means to create a new node and to insert it at the head, so that the new head is the new node:

```
typedef int ElemType;

typedef struct Stack Stack;

struct Stack {
    Stack *next;
    ElemType data;
};

void Push(Stack **S, ElemType e)
{
    Stack *newpt= malloc(sizeof(*newpt));

    newpt->data = e;
    newpt->next = (*S);
    *S = newpt;
}
```

Your code implements destruction of the stack, but more usually, stacks are exhausted py popping items off it. So let's imlement that:

```
ElemType Pop(Stack **S)
{
    ElemType res;
    Stack *rem = *S;

    if (*S == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack underflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    res = (*S)->data;
    *S = (*S)->next;
    free(rem);

    return res;
}
```

Note how we must keep copies of the data and the old pointer, because `free`ing the data akes it inaccessible.

Now we can rewrite the destruction function: We pop off items off the stack untilit is exhausted.

```
void DestroyStack(Stack **S)
{
    while (*S) Pop(S);
}
```

Finally, a traversal function that doesn't allocate anything:

```
void StackTraverse(const Stack *S)
{
    while (S) {
        printf("%d ", S->data);
        S = S->next;
    }

    puts("");
}
```

This function only inspects the stack; it doesn't mdofy it, so it is enough to pass the constant head poiner. Finally, the main function:

```
int main(){
    Stack *Sb = NULL;        
    ElemType e;

    while (scanf("%d", &e) == 1){
        Push(&Sb, e);
    }

    StackTraverse(Sb);
    DestroyStack(&Sb);

    return 0;
}
```

The element type is just an `int`, so it is a bit of an overkill to allocate memory dynamically for it. It is easier to use an automatic variable.

After this program has finished, all allocated blocks are freed.

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for such a detailed answer,I know my code seem such a mess to somebody ,but thank you for reading my scripts patiently and reply with such a long contend.So here is my question ,is it Ok ,to free the memory allocated to Stack with a pointer,I mean seems that you did not allocated momery to rem ,but you use free() on  it!

Comment: your answer is what i mean ! delete the memory .And i also learned a lot about a unique way to free memory which is allocated to variable by malloc()! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your solution 1 is wrong.

```
void DestroyStack(LinkStack *S){
    if(S){
        LinkStack pt = S;
        S = S->next;
        free(pt);
        printf("#a\n");
        DestroyStack(S);
        printf("LinkStack Destroyed!");
    }
}
```

Do note that you're passing **a pointer `*S`**, so don't mix `->` and the dereference operator (unary `*`). Also remember to `free` whatever you've allocated with `malloc`.

For solution 2, the correct code should look like this:

```
void DestroyStack(LinkStack *S){
    while(S){
        LinkStack pt = S->next;
        free(S);
        S = pt;
    }
    printf("Node destroyed!\n");
}
```

Remember, `S->next` is equivalent to `(*S).next`, don't mix them up. Also don't mix pointers up (`(*S)=pt` is definitely wrong). `S` is a pointer, and `*S` is a user-defined structure. You can't assign a pointer to a structure.

Comment: ,er......... firstly ,thank you for answering my question ,in fact I MISTAKEN the solution 1 and 2 ,the solution (originally solution 1) using Recrusion is in fact correct. And the origin solution 2 is wrong.But S is in fact a **Stack ,so I think maybe it is right to assign **Stack pt to **Stack S.So Sorry for my fault in editing questions. @iBug

Comment: @justinRen 直接打中文吧，拼音看起来好累

Comment: 就是我在输入的时候把Solution1和Solution2搞反了，使用迭代的那个函数其实是可以运行的

Answer (score 0):

in soluting1,whatever true or false in while,your code print "destory",hence the times you insert not equal to times you destory.it's a logic error and also you need free,you almost done it. 
I am not good at english,hope you can understand me

Comment: yes....I do understand ,and I made a mistake when  I publish the question.I mistaken solution 1 and solution 2 .I am so sorry.And thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You don't call `free(pt)` in solution 1, it goes into a loop for all the nodes and does not free anything.

A `free()` in C released the memory pointed by the pointer, the pointer still exists in the memory hence generally programmers write a wrapper function which frees the memory and points the pointer to a NULL.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! But in fact I do assignd the memory to the STACK in InitStack() ,which means I can use free.